# zipfile list of content from multiple paths

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm trying to get the list of all files in .zip that are in many different folders

To identify the paths of all .zip files I used this code:

```
import os, zipfile

path1 = 'C:\\desktop\\somefolderpath'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path1):
    for file in f:
        if '.zip' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    print(f)
```

with that I get the whole list:

```
C:\desktop\somefolderpath\1\folder1\zipfile1.zip
C:\desktop\somefolderpath\2\folder3\zipfile5.zip
...
```

And then I used .namelist to get the list of contents in certain .zip

```
zipPath = 'C:\\desktop\\somefolderpath\\1\\folder1\\zipfile1.zip'

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath)
print(zip.namelist())
```

How can I now use paths from "f" instead of writing paths everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate through the list as you have already done for printing out the filepaths-

```
import os, zipfile

path1 = 'C:\\desktop\\somefolderpath'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path1):
    for file in f:
        if '.zip' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for zipPath in files:
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath)
    print(zip.namelist())
```